# In cvs how do I obtain the author of a commit during the commitinfo or verifymsg hooks?

Tags: cvs

I need to perform some validation on the cvs user who is performing a commit, either in the commitinfo hook or the verifymsg hook.  Is there a way to obtain the user ID or name of the cvs user trying to commit; that is, not the local system user, instead the user listed in the CVSROOT/passwd file?

Answer (score 0):

There is an environment variable set that tells you the name of the cvs user:

```
CVS_USER=joebloggs
```

This isn't in the documentation.